# How to remove all hidden .unwanted directories from a tree?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to force remove any hidden directory named `.unwanted` from a directory tree using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).

I am hoping for a simple enough solution for an absolute novice to easily understand and to learn from. I know the commands `Get-ChildItem` and `Remove-Item` but I don't yet understand how to chain/pipe them with the new type of variables.

Comment: Why did you tag it batch file if you don't want batch file answers?

Comment: sorry, fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -Directory -Filter .unwanted |
  Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the removal; remove it to perform actual removal.</sup>

- `-Force` is needed in order to target hidden items (and, in the case of `Remove-Item` on Windows, to override the `r` (read-only) attribute, if permitted).
- `-Recurse` is needed to find directories in the entire subtree (`Get-ChildItem`) and to remove directories that are nonempty (`Remove-Item`) without a confirmation prompt.

As an aside: Use of `-Filter` is the most efficient way to locate the directories of interest, because it filters at the source, whereas (implied) use of `-Path` would make PowerShell enumerate all directories first and filter afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The supplied Bash code can be translated into the below code:

```
Get-Childitem *unwanted* -Recurse | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Depending on permissions, you may have to use the -Force parameter on the second command. I would also suggest performing some research and testing into these commands before using them in any sort of production environment. Things can get dangerous :)

I will also leave a good article on PowerShell Pipelines [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-6)

Comment: This does not seem to find a `.unwanted` directory unless it is directly underneath the current directory. I am trying `get-childitem .unwanted -recurse | Remove-Item` and now I get a popup saying `the item at microsoft.powershell.core\filesystem::D:\source\testdir\.unwanted has children and the recurse parameter was not specified. if you continue, all children will be removed with the item. are you sure you want to continue?`. It says the same using `Remove-Item -force`. How to do this without user confirmation?

Comment: That does not remove the confirmation

Comment: I believe I made a mistake, you should only use -Force and -Confirm seperately. I have removed -Force from my example and also added -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue. You can also find this same issue here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/03afb508-12f2-4173-a94d-273dc7b848b4/how-to-stop-getting-prompted-to-quotconfirmquot?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: It works now, but it turns out my `.unwanted` directories are hidden and this solution only deleted non-hidden ones. I tried adding `-Force` to the `Get-ChildItem` so it returns the hidden ones too but it fails to delete them.

Comment: What error are you getting when it tries to delete them? You will need to remove the -ErrorAction preference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193026/discussion-between-bricktop-and-i-t-delinquent).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this based on your requirement -

```
Get-ChildItem -path \\PathToYourFolder\ -recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -eq ".unwanted"} | Remove-Item
```

In simple words, a `PowerShell` pipeline takes the output of the `cmdlets` on it's left side and passes it as input to the `cmdlets` on its right side.

The command `where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true` uses the `PsIsContainer` property of all file system objects to select only folders, which have a value of True ($true) in their `PsIsContainer` property.

Comment: This is not as easily readable/understandable than the other answer, plus it has the same problem: it asks for user confirmation.